# Is there a way to block pings/notifications of a specific user?

Tags: support, notifications, comment-replies

Is there a way to block pings/notifications of a specific user? If possible, on a specific question?

---

I did a quick search through the first pages of the entries "ping", "block", "notifications" etc and couldn't find anything, just [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-block-questions-coming-from-specific-users) not so related post. Sorry if this was already discussed.

Comment: Somewhat related post on meta.SE: [How to deal with comment abuse?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132919/how-to-deal-with-comment-abuse). (I did not find a post there which was closer to this one.)

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any block feature on the main site, only in chat.

If a particular user is pinging you excessively, just ask them to stop. If they don't stop after being asked to, flag for moderator attention and explain the situation.

To some extent the absence of such a feature is intentional. Ignoring users that misbehave doesn't actually solve the problem, those users can continue to misbehave towards other users that don't have them blocked yet. If a user doesn't stop problematic behaviour after it was pointed out to them, a suspension might be necessary. So the mechanism to deal with such users are the moderators that handle exceptional situations, which makes a blocking feature for this use case superfluous.

Comment: Has this been discussed before somewhere? Is the inexistence of such feature intentional?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I added a bit about the rationale for the absence of this feature.

Comment: I understand the reasoning, but that reasoning is from the *system's* point of view. My intention of ignoring a certain user has not to be related to a increase of overall quality of the whole website, but to a increase of the overall quality of my experience on the website. It is a personal decision, which affects only myself. This is the principle which allows blocking on Facebook, MSN, e-mails etc. Why doesn't this principle apply here?